# $.ajaxFileUpload is firing GET and POST call, is there a way stop the GET call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-file-upload

This is my code and it is firing a GET call before the POST, I couldn't handle response because of the GET call is getting failed, is there a way to handle this situation ?

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
            url: '/DigitalFileCabinet/UploadFile/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            secureuri: true,
            async: false,
            data: { id: dfcId },
            fileElementId: "Notes",
            success: function (response, status) {
                if (status == 'success') {
                    if (response == false) {
                        alert("Notes file upload error! please try again.");
                    }
                    DigitalFileCabinet.ReloadGridManually(grid);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, e) {
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
                if (status === 'success')
                    return;
                else
                    return alert('Failed to upload Notes!');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a GET call and not an OPTIONS call (i.e. CORS)?

Comment: @John it is showing the type as get, not OPTIONS

Comment: Can you show the whole form? And is your button is a submit type? How do you call the the ajaxFileUpload?

Comment: actually I am calling the ajaxFileUpload inside the jqGrid "afterSubmit" ..
after submitting a specific form